# No internet connection on install [14.04]

Tags: system-installation, internet

I decided to install ubuntu as my 2nd OS (Together with Windows 8 x64 non-UEFI), made an USB drive with installer of Ubuntu 14.04. But when loading is done, ubuntu installer asked me to connect to WiFi (I am already have wired connection), if I press NO, I CAN check "install updates" but after 3-5 seconds it says that I have no internet connection, if yes, nothing happens! "Hmm.. ok". When I press continue, nothing happens, just a spinning cursor.

But if I press EXIT, I can open firefox and everything is ok with the internet. If I open installer again, it still think that I have no Internet but now I can install Ubuntu (at the middle of installation it even loads something from the internet!).

Can anybody say to me wtf is that?
PS: I tried cd, usb, another image (14.10 instead of 14.04 and 14.04.1), another burner (pendrivelinux, unetbootin, rufus, ultraiso) but everytime I have the same problem.

Comment: It may be a problem with the mirror servers. BTW why don't you install Ubuntu without updates, then after the installation update all your packages?

Answer (score 0):

While I have never seen behavior such as you describe, I find myself asking
if it's possible that the wireless card is recognized and configured. When I did my install, I had no wifi access, but soon discovered that my card was not set up. Broadcom wireless cards require some special effort. Searching for 'Broadcom wifi' will get info that is needed for driver installation. There are several steps required, but the information I found provided great detail and I was able to do this driver install 2 times (upgraded from 12.10 to 14.04 LTS).  Hope this helps  Craig

Comment: The problem is not in wifi, because I was connected via lan (Realtek).
I believe they fixed it in 14.04.3, because now it works great.